# Поиск данных в кэше перебирая массив, или все-таки из базы?

Tags: php, memcached

Есть у меня список товаров, я эти товары сериализовал и добавил в мемкеш, и при выводе вывожу из кэша.

Но вот какой интересный момент, если мне нужно использовать поиск по товару (применить фильтр), цену например, мне в кэше нужно будет пройтись по всем 5000 элементам массива, и посмотреть у каждого цену.

Не лучше в таком моменте будет использовать sql запрос, и затронуть базу?

Как вообще реализуется это, если есть кэш?

Comment: memcached разве массивы разучился хранить? Зачем тратить время на сериализацию и обратное восстановление?

Comment: @Visman ну можно и просто сжимать используя MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: Я бы вам предложил протестировать тот и другой варианты и сравнить.

Comment: @Visman протестировать можно, да, просто решил узнать, какой алгоритм применяется в подобных ситуациях, может я в корне неправильно думаю